# Appropriate use of friend? Container class designed to manipulate objects of specific type

Tags: c++, collections, private, friend

Lets say you have a `FooManager` made to manage multiple objects of type `Foo`. The `FooManager` needs to see some parts of its `Foo`s to evaluate their current state. Before I was using a few accessors in `Foo` to see these parts, until I realized that `FooManager` is the only class actually using these. I decided to make `FooManager` a friend of `Foo`. This resulted in most of class `Foo` becoming private.

Is this an appropriate use of friend? My reasoning was that it helps encapsulation because while it gives `FooManager` complete access to `Foo`'s internals, it completely blocks off access to everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a different and cleaner way to achieve what you're trying to achieve, this sounds like a fair approach.

With regards to encapsulation, see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2.

Comment: I actually used the Attorney-Client idiom that one guy posted, but unfortunately his answer his gone. Oh well.